# R get swipeR to display in a loop for html markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a list of images that I would like to render as a carousel in an html markdown. This works fine if it just a single print out, however it fails to do so in a loop. Here is an example

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, collapse = TRUE)
library(plotly)
library(swipeR)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)
```

```{r fig=TRUE,fig.width=20, fig.height=14, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE, results='asis' }


# Your list of ggplots
# Your list of ggplots
g1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 1")
g2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 2")
g3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, wt)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Plot 3")

wrapper <- swipeRwrapper(
  tags$div(style = "width: 500px; margin: auto;", ggplotly(g1)),
  tags$div(style = "width: 500px; margin: auto;", ggplotly(g2)),
  tags$div(style = "width: 500px; margin: auto;", ggplotly(g3))
)

# this works fine when not in a loop
swipeR(wrapper, height = "400px", navigationColor = "navy")

# this fails when in a loop 


output <- tagList()
for (i in 1:2) {
  output <- tagList(
    output,
    tags$div( swipeR(wrapper, height = "400px", navigationColor = "navy")  )
  )
  
}

html_output <- renderTags(output)
cleaned_html <- gsub('\\\\', '', html_output$html)

cat ( cleaned_html) # does'nt work 

## try just pasting instead

output <- ""
for (i in 1:2) {
  rendered_output <- renderTags(tags$div(style = "width: 500px; margin: auto;", swipeR(wrapper, height = "400px", navigationColor = "navy") ))
  output <- paste(output, rendered_output$html, sep = "\n")
}

cat(output)# does'nt work 

 
```

# I tried two methods but both does not not seem to work correctly.
````

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent There are instances where I have many different sets of images I would like to render. For example, I might have set1 for experiment 1 and then set2 for another experiment. Thus, I try to simulate that with the for ```loop 1:2``` however when inside a loop for whatever reason the images cannot be rendered. Usually I can use htmltools but in doesn't seem to work.